# Why is trypsin digestion required for proteomic studies?

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteomics

I know that trypsin is used for proteomic studies, but I do not understand why trypsin digestion is necessary/important.

Comment: Welcome to SE biology. Could you edit your question to make it clearer. Proteomics is not a synonym for mass spectrometry. I think you want to ask `Why is tryptic digestion used prior to mass spectrometry?`

Answer (score 0):

Trypsin digestion allows you to cut proteins into smaller polypeptides, masses of which can be determined by mass spectrometry and then translated back into possible amino acid sequences. Trypsin cleaves after specific amino acids. Altogether, this allows you to identify proteins.